# How can I check if an object is an iterator in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

I can check for a `next()` method, but is that enough?  Is there an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or better, the designed-in idiom for such behavioral checks is a "membership check" with the abstract base class in the `collections` module of the standard library:

```
>>> import collections
>>> isinstance('ciao', collections.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(23, collections.Iterable)
False
>>> isinstance(xrange(23), collections.Iterable)
True
```

Indeed, this kind of checks is the prime design reason for the new abstract base classes (a second important one is to provide "mixin functionality" in some cases, which is why they're ABCs rather than just interfaces -- but that doesn't apply to `collections.Iterable`, it exists *strictly* to allow such checks with `isinstance` or `issubclass`).  ABCs allow classes that don't actually inherit from them to be "registered" as subclasses anyway, so that such classes can be "subclasses" of the ABC for such checks; and, they can internally perform all needed checks for special methods (`__iter__` in this case), so you don't have to.

If you're stuck with older releases of Python, "it's better to ask forgiveness than permission":

```
def isiterable(x):
  try: iter(x)
  except TypeError: return False
  else: return True
```

but that's not as fast and concise as the new approach.

Note that for this special case you'll often want to special-case strings (which are iterable but most application contexts want to treat as "scalars" anyway).  Whatever approach you're using to check iterableness, if you need such special casing just prepend a check for `isinstance(x, basestring)` -- for example:

```
def reallyiterable(x):
  return not isinstance(x, basestring) and isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)
```

**Edit**: as pointed out in a comment, the question focuses on whether an object is an iter***ator*** rather than whether it's iter***able*** (all iterators are iterable, but not vice versa -- not all iterables are iterators).  `isinstance(x, collections.Iterator)` is the perfectly analogous way to check for that condition specifically.

Comment: The questions asks if an object is an iterator, not if it is iterable.  So you should use collections.Iterator instead of collections.Iterable

Comment: In Python 3.8 and up, looks like `collections.Iterator` will instead be `collections.abc.Iterator`. Python 3.7 issues a deprecation warning for this: "Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working".

Comment: And iterator and being iterable are not the same thing. `[]` is iterable, but it is not an iterator.

Answer (score 19):

An object is iterable if it implements the iterator protocol.
You could check the presence of `__iter__()` method with:

```
hasattr(object,'__iter__')
```

in Python 2.x this approach misses str objects and other built-in sequence types like unicode, xrange, buffer. It works in Python 3.

Another way is to test it with iter method :

```
try:
   iter(object)
except TypeError:
   #not iterable
```

Comment: Creating iterator could be expensive whereas checking attribute existence is always *fast*.

Comment: this checks if the object is *iterable*, not it if is an *iterator*

Answer (score 10):

To be an iterator an object must pass three tests:

- `obj` has an `__iter__` method
- `obj` has a `next` method (or `__next__` in Python 3)
- `obj.__iter__()` returns `obj`

So, a roll-your-own test would look like:

```
def is_iterator(obj):
    if (
            hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and
            hasattr(obj, 'next') and      # or __next__ in Python 3
            callable(obj.__iter__) and
            obj.__iter__() is obj
        ):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Would calling `obj.__iter__()` run the risk of changing something?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: Only if the object is buggy.

Comment: @EthanFurman What do you mean? If `obj` is an iterator, then yes, it shouldn't change something. But if `obj` is not an iterator, `obj.__iter__()` is allowed to have side effects.

Comment: @PyRulez:  Presumably BobStein's question was about iterators, and my answer was definitely about iterators; if the `obj` in question is not, in fact, an iterator then my answer to him doesn't apply.

Comment: @EthanFurman hmm? Wouldn't that mean you could just return true then?

Comment: @PyRulez: No.  Please ask a new question if you're still confused.  ;)

Comment: Just for clarity, it might help to distinguish between "iterable" and "iterator" here. Lists are iterable, but they are not iterators. `hasattr([1,2,3], '__next__') == False`, but `hasattr([1,2,3], '__iter__') == True`

Answer (score 9):

There is a better method than other answers have suggested.

In Python we have two kinds of things: `Iterable` and `Iterator`. An object is `Iterable` if it can give you `Iterator`. It does so when you use `iter()` on it. An object is `Iterator` if you can use `next()` to sequentially browse through its elements. For example, `map()` returns `Iterator` and `list` is `Iterable`.

Here are [more details](https://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/).

Below code illustrates how to check for these types:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator

r = [1, 2, 3]
e = map(lambda x:x, r)

print(isinstance(r, Iterator)) # False, because can't apply next
print(isinstance(e, Iterator)) # True
print(isinstance(r, Iterable)) # True, because can apply iter()
print(isinstance(e, Iterable)) # True, note iter() returns self
```

Answer (score 6):

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

isinstance(object, Iterator)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

answer from python sourcecode doc comments:

**{python install path}/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/types.py**

```
# Iterators in Python aren't a matter of type but of protocol.  A large
# and changing number of builtin types implement *some* flavor of
# iterator.  Don't check the type!  Use hasattr to check for both
# "__iter__" and "__next__" attributes instead.
```

Comment: And this improves on the existing answers how?

Answer (score 0):

This example comes from the book *Effective Python* and is illustrated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31245371/3293726).

> An iterable produces an iterator. Any iterator is also an iterable,
>   but produces itself as the iterator:
>
> ```
> >>> list_iter = iter([])
> >>> iter(list_iter) is list_iter
> True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to check if the value is **iterable** you can do something like:

```
>>> from typing import Iterable

>>> isinstance([], Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(1, Iterable)
False
```

If you want to check if it's an **iterator** you can do something like:

```
>>> hasattr(obj, "__iter__") and hasattr(obj, "__next__")
True
```

Comment: Funny how most answers to this questions check if the object is an iterable, rather than an iterator. It's relevant to add the reference to the more recent `typing` here, but please add the example checking for `Iterator`, since that's the actual question.

Comment: @joanis definitely, makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm surprised by the solution you chose. I just tested, and `isinstance(iter([]), Iterator)` returns `True`, while `isinstance([], Iterator)` returns `False`, so I would have expected your edit to use `from typing import Iterator` and `isinstance` with it.

Comment: I personally prefer to check explicitly for `__iter__` and `__next__` dunder methods - you can do that too.. I guess it's just preference. - I'm happy to add it too.

Comment: Thinking about this - iter() on a non iterator will raise @joanis - not really best approach.

Comment: I guess checking for those two dunder methods is the standard solution, and probably exactly what `isinstance(object, Iterator)` actually does under the hood, so maybe you're right, that's the best solution to keep here.

Comment: I would definitely not call `iter(object)` just to test if it's an iterator, to avoid incurring any run-time costs an unknown object's iterator creation might require.

Comment: Sounds good, glad we came to the same conclusion :D have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
if '__iter__' in dir(object):
   #code
else:
   #code
```

Comment: This will test that object is *iterable*, not whether it's an *iterator*.

Answer (score -4):

As the question is about Iterator not Iterable and considering usage of iterator, a simplest and pythonic way of doing this

```
iterable = [1,2]
iterator = iter(iterable)


def isIterator(obj):
    try:
        next(obj, None)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False

>>> isIterator(iterable)
False
>>> isIterator(iterator)
True
```

Yes. Checking on next() should be enough

Comment: If it's enough, it's also way too much! Using next() advances the iterator. Data is being thrown away for a type check! This would never be reliable in real world use cases.

Comment: @Zim Since OP mentioned, they can use next() method I dont think it was a problem. For example, I can try to iterate, based on error message if it is not an iterator then I may have logic to handle a different data type. So it is purely depends on your need. Can you elaborate real world use case you have in mind?