# What's the best way of skip N values of the iteration variable in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

In many languages we can do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        i += 10;
    }
}
```

**How can I do the same in Python?** The following (of course) does not work:

```
for i in xrange(value):
    if condition:
        i += 10
```

I could do something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < value:
  if condition:
    i += 10
  i += 1
```

but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant (*pythonic?*) way of doing this in Python.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `continue`.

```
for i in xrange(value):
    if condition:
        continue
```

If you want to force your iterable to skip forwards, you must call `.next()`.

```
>>> iterable = iter(xrange(100))
>>> for i in iterable:
...     if i % 10 == 0:
...         [iterable.next() for x in range(10)]
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
```

As you can see, this is disgusting.

Comment: Please, check my last edit. I changed it to skip 10 values of *i* instead of only one.

Comment: It depends on what your trying to do, what are you looping over, and why are you using i as the counter?  The more pythonic way may be not to use the "counter" at all.  It's hard to say without a more detailed example.

Comment: Iterators don't allow you to 'jump ahead' by an arbitrary number of steps. The only way to skip ahead is to call `.next()` on your iterator the number of times you want to skip.

Comment: @brad.ayers can you post an example of how to call `.next()` in the code you posted?

Comment: @brad.ayers thanks. I just wanted to see another way of doing this, although I think I will keep using the `while` ;)

Comment: @brad.ayers, itertools.islice does the jump ahead on an iterator.  Spend some time looking at itertools, you will fall in love.  islice handles the next() calls for you.

Comment: Your output is slightly off.  It prints "0, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,31,32" etc

Comment: @mydogisbox How so? I just copy/pasted the code into a Python interpreter and I get the output I have in my answer, please elaborate.

Comment: @bradley.ayers Interesting, maybe there is a bug in the iron python interpreter I'm using.  It gives me the output I posted.

Answer (score 23):

Create the iterable before the loop.

Skip one by using next on the iterator

```
it = iter(xrange(value))
for i in it:
    if condition:
        i = next(it)
```

Skip many by using itertools or recipes based on ideas from itertools.

[itertools.dropwhile()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
it = iter(xrange(value))
for i in it:
    if x<5:
        i = dropwhile(lambda x: x<5, it)
```

Take a read through the itertools page, it shows some very common uses of working with iterators.

itertools islice

```
it = islice(xrange(value), 10)
for i in it:
    ...do stuff with i...
```

Comment: the first code returns the following exception: `TypeError: xrange object is not an iterator`. I think it will require to specify: `it = xrange(value).__iter__()`

Comment: @oscar, thx.  I was just going off the top of my head.  Just wrap it in an iter() call to instantiate an iterator.

Comment: @oscar, takewhile was not quite what you may have been looking for, I changed it to dropwhile.  If you simply want skip over a bunch of an iterator, islice can do that quite affectively if it is a qtantity.

Answer (score 6):

It's a very old question, but I find the accepted answer is not totally stisfactory:

- first, after the `if ... / [next()...]` sequence, the value of `i` hasn't changed. In your first example, it has.
- second, the list comprehension is used to produce a side-effect. This should be avoided.
- third, there might be a faster way to achieve this.

Using a modified version of `consume` in [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), you can write:

```
import itertools

def consume(it, n):
    return next(itertools.islice(it, n-1, n), None)

it = iter(range(20))
for i in it:
    print(i, end='->')
    if i%4 == 0:
        i = consume(it, 5)
    print(i)
```

As written in the doctstring of `consume`, the iterator is consumed at C speed (didn't benchmark though). Output:

```
0->5
6->6
7->7
8->13
14->14
15->15
16->None
```

With a minor modification, one can get `21` instead of `None`, but I think this isnot a good idea because this code does work with any iterable (otherwise one would prefer the `while` version):

```
import string
it = iter(string.ascii_lowercase) # a-z
for x in it:
    print(x, end="->")
    if x in set('aeiouy'):
        x = consume(it, 2) # skip the two letters after the vowel
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
a->c
d->d
e->g
h->h
i->k
l->l
m->m
n->n
o->q
r->r
s->s
t->t
u->w
x->x
y->None
```

Comment: it should be `n` not in `n-1` in consume()

Comment: @SmartManoj I just tested it with : `>>> it = iter(range(10)) / >>> list(it) / [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] / >>> it = iter(range(10)) / >>> consume(it, 4) / 3 / >>> list(it) / 
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Seems ok to me.

Comment: if it is n, consume returns None else the last consumed element

Answer (score 4):

Itertools has a recommended way to do this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

```
import collections
def tail(n, iterable):
    "Return an iterator over the last n items"
    # tail(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> E F G
    return iter(collections.deque(iterable, maxlen=n))
```

Now you can do:

```
for i in tail(5, range(10)):
    print(i)
```

to get

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: This does kind of the opposite of the request. The request is to "skip N items", but this answer shows how to skip *all but* N items. Obv this isn't too difficult to account for if the total number of items is known ahead-of-time, but that isn't always known. It also wastefully forces all items to be consumed immediately. (It isn't wasteful if you *actually want* tail, but it's wasteful compared to what we really want, which is `isplice(iter, N, None)`.)

Comment: @tho What about the consume function in that recipe?

Comment: @josh isplice from?

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping I am not answering this wrong... but this is the simplest way I have come across:

```
for x in range(0,10,2):
    print x
```

output should be something like this:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

The 2 in the range parameter's is the jump value

Answer (score 0):

Does a generator function here is rebundant?
Like this:

```
def filterRange(range, condition):
x = 0
while x < range:
    x = (x+10) if condition(x) else (x + 1)
    yield x

if __name__ == "__main__":
for i in filterRange(100, lambda x: x > 2):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to [create iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880), but the [custom iterator class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36230057/208880) is the most extensible:

```
class skip_if:   # skip_if(object) for python2
    """
    iterates through iterable, calling skipper with each value
    if skipper returns a positive integer, that many values are
    skipped
    """
    def __init__(self, iterable, skipper):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.skip = skipper
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):   # def next(self): for python2
        value = next(self.it)
        for _ in range(self.skip(value)):
            next(self.it, None)
        return value
```

and in use:

```
>>> for i in skip_if(range(1,100), lambda n: 10 if not n%10 else 0):
...   print(i, end=', ')
... 
 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,
81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90,
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `more_itertools.consume()`. See https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consume.

```
import more_itertools

x = iter(range(10))

# skip the next four items
more_itertools.consume(x, 4)
y = list(x)
print(y)
```

will result in

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This becomes super helpful if you are iterating through a file and need to skip a bunch of lines. Something like this:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    while line:= next(file):

        # Look for "magic_word" and then skip 10 lines.
        if "magic_word" in line:
            more_itertools.consume(file, 10)
    
        # do other stuff with line
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use a while loop for this...for loop loops over an iterable..and you cannot skip next item like how you want to do it here