# Skip multiple iterations in loop

Tags: python, loops, iterator, continue

I have a list in a loop and I want to skip 3 elements after `look` has been reached.
In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509302/whats-the-best-way-of-skip-n-values-of-the-iteration-variable-in-python) a couple of suggestions were made but I fail to make good use of them:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
for sing in song:
    if sing == 'look':
        print sing
        continue
        continue
        continue
        continue
        print 'a' + sing
    print sing
```

Four times `continue` is nonsense of course and using four times `next()` doesn't work.

The output should look like:

```
always
look
aside
of
life
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`for` uses `iter(song)` to loop; you can do this in your own code and then advance the iterator inside the loop; calling `iter()` on the iterable again will only return the same iterable object so you can advance the iterable inside the loop with `for` following right along in the next iteration.

Advance the iterator with the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next); it works correctly in both Python 2 and 3 without having to adjust syntax:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)
for sing in song_iter:
    print sing
    if sing == 'look':
        next(song_iter)
        next(song_iter)
        next(song_iter)
        print 'a' + next(song_iter)
```

By moving the `print sing` line up we can avoid repeating ourselves too.

Using `next()` this way *can* raise a `StopIteration` exception, if the iterable is out of values.

You could catch that exception, but it'd be easier to give `next()` a second argument, a default value to ignore the exception and return the default instead:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)
for sing in song_iter:
    print sing
    if sing == 'look':
        next(song_iter, None)
        next(song_iter, None)
        next(song_iter, None)
        print 'a' + next(song_iter, '')
```

I'd use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip 3 elements instead; saves repeated `next()` calls:

```
from itertools import islice

song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)
for sing in song_iter:
    print sing
    if sing == 'look':
        print 'a' + next(islice(song_iter, 3, 4), '')
```

The `islice(song_iter, 3, 4)` iterable will skip 3 elements, then return the 4th, then be done. Calling `next()` on that object thus retrieves the 4th element from `song_iter()`.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
>>> song_iter = iter(song)
>>> for sing in song_iter:
...     print sing
...     if sing == 'look':
...         print 'a' + next(islice(song_iter, 3, 4), '')
... 
always
look
aside
of
life
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
>>> count = 0
>>> while count < (len(song)):
    if song[count] == "look" :
        print song[count]
        count += 4
        song[count] = 'a' + song[count]
        continue
    print song[count]
    count += 1

Output:

always
look
aside
of
life
```

Comment: Works for that specific artificial example, but wouldn't work appropriately on arbitrary iterators/generators, where going to the next element or skipping is possible, but fetching an arbitrary element by index is either impossible (if they aren't stored) or slow.

Answer (score 4):

I think, it's just fine to use iterators and `next` here:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
it = iter(song)
while True:
    word = next(it, None)
    if not word:
       break
    print word
    if word == 'look':
        for _ in range(4): # skip 3 and take 4th
            word = next(it, None)
        if word:
            print 'a' + word
```

or, with exception handling (which is shorter as well as more robust as @Steinar noticed):

```
it = iter(song)
while True:
    try:
        word = next(it)
        print word
        if word == 'look':
            for _ in range(4):
                word = next(it)
            print 'a' + word 
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: This works for the case presented, but be aware that any item which evaluates to False will break this solution (e.g `['always', 'look', '', 'the']` or `['always', 'look', None, 'the']`)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without an iter() as well simply using an extra variable:

```
skipcount = -1
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
for sing in song:
    if sing == 'look' and skipcount <= 0:
        print sing
        skipcount = 3
    elif skipcount > 0:
        skipcount = skipcount - 1
        continue
    elif skipcount == 0:
        print 'a' + sing
        skipcount = skipcount - 1
    else:
        print sing
        skipcount = skipcount - 1
```

Comment: This is rather unreadable though; it is really hard to work out what the intention is here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: agreed that there will be better solutions. Just wanted to point out a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, using .next() three times is not nonsense. When you want to skip n values, call next() n+1 times (don't forget to assign the value of the last call to something) and then "call" continue.

To get an exact replica of the code you posted:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
songiter = iter(song)
for sing in songiter:
  if sing == 'look':
    print sing
    songiter.next()
    songiter.next()
    songiter.next()
    sing = songiter.next()
    print 'a' + sing
    continue
  print sing
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use three time next (here I actually do it four time)

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
it = iter(song)
for sing in it:
    if sing == 'look':
        print sing
        try:
           sing = it.next(); sing = it.next(); sing = it.next(); sing=it.next()
        except StopIteration:
             break
        print 'a'+sing
    else:
        print sing
```

Then

```
always
look
aside
of
life
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code is the simplest for me.

```
# data list
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

# this is one possible way
for sing in song:
    if sing != 'look'\
            and sing != 'always' \
            and sing != 'side' \
            and sing != 'of'\
            and sing != 'life':
        continue
    if sing == 'side':
        sing = f'a{sing}'  # or sing = 'aside'
    print(sing)

# this is another possible way
songs_to_keep = ['always', 'look', 'of', 'side', 'of', 'life']
songs_to_change = ['side']
for sing in song:
    if sing not in songs_to_keep:
        continue
    if sing in songs_to_change:
        sing = f'a{sing}'
    print(sing)
```

This produces the results you are looking for.

```
always
look
aside
of
life
```