# Efficiently Iterating over dictionary list values by skipping missing values Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Location': [ 'NY', 'SF', 'NY', 'NY', 'SF', 'SF', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'DC'],
                 'Class': ['H','L','H','L','L','H', 'H','L','L','M'],
                 'Address': ['12 Silver','10 Fak','12 Silver','1 North','10 Fak','2 Fake', '1 Red','1 Dog','2 Fake','1 White'],
                 'Score':['4','5','3','2','1','5','4','3','2','1',]})
```

And I want to add 2 tags which I stored in dictionaries. Note that the second dictionary does not include key 'A'

```
df['Tag1'] =''
df['Tag2'] =''

tagset1 = {'A':['NY|SF'],
          'B':['DC'],
          'C':['TX'],
          }
for key in tagset1:
    df.loc[df.Location.str.contains(tagset1[key][0]) & (df.Tag1 == ''),'Tag1'] = key


tagset2= {'B':['H|M'],
          'C':['L'],
          }
for key in tagset2:
    df.loc[df.Class.str.contains(tagset2[key][0]) & (df.Tag2 == ''),'Tag2'] = key

print (df)
```

If I want to combine the both dictionaries to make the code more readable and efficient should I fill in the spot for A in `newtagset['A'][1]` with `''` or is there another way to make the iterator ignore or skip position `newtagset['A'][1]` when iterating over the position in the list?

```
newtagset = {'A':['NY|SF', '',],
          'B':['DC','H|M',],
          'C':['TX','L',],
          }


for key in newtagset:
    df.loc[df.Location.str.contains(newtagset[key][0]) & (df.Tag1 == ''),'Tag1'] = key

for key in newtagset:
    df.loc[df.Class.str.contains(newtagset[key][1]) & (df.Tag2 == ''),'Tag2'] = key

print (df)
```

Most solutions I found uses itertools [Skip multiple iterations in loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295901/skip-multiple-iterations-in-loop-python) is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with simple `continue`.

```
for key, value in newtagset.items():    # I found dict.items cleaner
    if not value[1]:
        continue
    df.loc...
```

A bit of off topic:

`& (df.Tag1 == '')` is redundant. I would be useful only if you had coincidences in values, but that would lead to unpredictable behavior, since dict is not ordered.