# Skip variable number of iterations in Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

I have a list and a for loop such as these:

```
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar,'bar','hello']
for item in mylist:
    cp = mylist.count(item)
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(cp)+" copy(ies)")
```

Output:

```
You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
You dude are present in 1 copy(ies)
```

**Expected output:**

```
You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
You dude are present in 1 copy(ies)
```

The idea is thus to skip a variable number of iterations within the for loop, using something like this script (**not working**):

```
for item in mylist:
    cp = mylist.count(item)
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(cp)+" copy(ies)")
    continue(cp)
```

The script would thus "jump" `cp` elements in the for loop at every round and start doing again what it is asked at the item `item + cp`.

I know that you can use `continue` to skip multiple iterations (such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295901/skip-multiple-iterations-in-loop-python)) but I cannot figure out how to use `continue` to skip a **variable number of iterations**.

Thanks for your answer! :)

---

Edit: similar items are always next to each other.

Comment: is this list always sorted/grouped e.g. same elements are always together?

Comment: @Jerzyk yes indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']
c = Counter(mylist)
for item, cp in c.items():
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(cp)+" copy(ies)")
```

Comment: `Counter` object has no attribute `iteritems`

Comment: @pythad this is python 2 not 3. Use `items()` in 3

Comment: Updated answer to use `items` as that will work in both 2 and 3. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use collections.Counter for your job:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['foo', 'foo', 'bar'])
Counter({'foo': 2, 'bar': 1})
```

Thus,

```
count_dict = Counter(mylist)
for item in count_dict:
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(count_dict[item[)+" copy(ies)")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the elements are consecutive, you could use a `groupby` which would group the consecutive strings, it is just a matter of summing the length of each group to get the count:

```
from itertools import groupby
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']

for k,v in groupby(mylist):
    print("You {} are present in {} copy(ies)".format(k, sum(1 for _ in v)))
```

Output:

```
You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
You hello are present in 1 copy(ies)
```

The most efficient way to generally get counts would be to use the dictionary logic like a *Counter* provided in the other answers, if you want to keep order you could use an *OrderedDict* to do the counting:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']
od = OrderedDict()
for ele in mylist:
    od.setdefault(ele, 0)
    od[ele] += 1

for tup in od.items():
    print("You {} are present in {} copy(ies)".format(*tup))
```

Which would output the same:

```
You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
You hello are present in 1 copy(ies)
```

Both the *groupby* and the *dict* logic are `O(n)`, using your `list.count` is quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the unique elements of a list using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']
uniq_list = set(my_list)
for item in uniq_list:
    cp = mylist.count(item)
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(cp)+" copy(ies)")
```

Output:

> You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
>
> You hello are present in 1 copy(ies)
>
> You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)

Comment: This is `O(n^2)` as opposed to `O(n)` using a Counter

Comment: I am aware of that but the question was not to find the fastest solution but how to do it. In case the list gets really long, a different approach would make certainly make sense.

Comment: this also creates a new ``set`` for every iteration.

Comment: At the time of my comment this had two more votes than the Counter approach so for future readers it is worth pointing out

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: Your approach is certainly more flexible and faster, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way

```
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']
prev = None
for item in mylist:
    if item != prev:
        cp = mylist.count(item)
        print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(cp)+" copy(ies)")
        prev = item
```

hope  it may help !

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']
last = None
for item in mylist:
    if item is last:
        continue

    last = item
    cp = mylist.count(item)
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(cp)+" copy(ies)")
```

This assumes that the list is ordered so that identical objects are next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

[set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and [list counts](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm) would do the trick:

```
mylist = ['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','hello']
for item in set(mylist):
    print("You "+item+" are present in "+str(mylist.count(item))+" copy(ies)")
```

output:

> ```
> You foo are present in 3 copy(ies)
> You bar are present in 2 copy(ies)
> You hello are present in 1 copy(ies)
> ```