# How to make index in "for" loop jump forward by N

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I want for loop to change its pass behavior

For example, make it jump every 3rd index to another 2 positions?

```
for i in range(n):
   if i % 3 == 0:
     print('found i div by 3, jump 2 positions forward')
     i = i + 2
```

This does not work.

It goes through every `i` in range from 0 to `n`.

Comment: What do you mean by this does not work? Are you getting any error or wrong output?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it can't jump forward, it goes thru every i  - 0 to n

Comment: It seems to work okay, printed 4 times `found i div by 3, jump 2 positions forward` for range 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip multiple iterations in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295901/skip-multiple-iterations-in-loop)

Comment: @Georgy no thx bro ! i accepted the answer. it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a while loop,

```py
i = 0
while i < n:
   if i % 3 == 0:
     print('found i div by 3, jump 2 positions forward')
     i = i + 2
     continue
   i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

1. if you just want a step other than 1, `range` has a parameter for that, just call `range(0, 10, 3)` and it'll iterate from 0 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive) incrementing by 3 each time rather than 1
2. if you want to do something else and the skip condition is dynamic, don't use iterators, manage your loop manually (using a `while` and an explicit counter), that's what I'd recommend here
3. alternatively to (2) you can mess with the iterator itself, a `for` loop desugars to:

   ```py
   it = iter(range(n))
   while True:
       try:
           i = next(it)
       except StopIteration:
           break
       ...
   ```

   so if you get the `it` manually and keep a reference to it, you can call `next` on it explicitly to skip ahead:

   ```py
   it = iter(range(n))
   for i in it:
       if i % 3 == 0:
           print('found i div by 3, jump 2 positions forward')
           next(it, None); next(it, None)
   ```

   I would *not* recommend the second style, the first one already tells the reader upfront that you're doing something weird, and it does it in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify step-size in `for` loop if you want values divisible by 3

```
for i in range(0, n, 3):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
3
6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the slice operator `[::]` to change the original range according to a condition

```
l= range(n)

for i in l:
    if i%3 == 0:
        print('found i div by 3, jump 2 positions forward')
        l = l[::2]
```