# Is it possible to skip a fixed number of iterations in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator, continue

## Introduction:

So I know that there is already a question ([Skip multiple iterations in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22295901/17113459)) similar to mine with a really good answer, but there are still some open questions for me:

---

### Question 1:

##### Is there any way of doing it without an iterator?

I am looking for something like *** 3**:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

for sing in song:
    print(sing, end=" ")
    if sing == 'look':
        continue * 3
```

expected output:

```
always look side of life
```

---

### Question 2:

##### If I have to use an iterator object, then is it possible to do it a fixed amount of time?

The original question has a solution like this:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)
for sing in song_iter:
    print(sing)
    if sing == 'look':

        next(song_iter)
        next(song_iter)
        next(song_iter)

        print(next(song_iter))
```

But I want it to do it let's say **x = 5** times. It is not possible like this:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)
for sing in song_iter:
    print(sing)
    if sing == 'look':

        next(song_iter) * x

        print(next(song_iter))
```

So how would you do it? I know it is possible to use the function [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), but is there a way without any libraries?

---

#### My Approach:

This works great:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)

skip_iterations = 3

for sing in song_iter:
    print(sing)
    if sing == "look":
        while skip_iterations > 0:
            next(song_iter, "")

            skip_iterations -= 1
```

**Output:**

```
always look side of life
```

But maybe anyone else has a better idea? :)

---

##### Links:

[The Question I was mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22295901/17113459) -
[The Answer for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296065/17113459)

Comment: your approach seems good enough, except I would use a `for` loop: `for _ in range(skip_iterations): next(song_iter)`

Comment: Every `for` loop uses an iterator, whether you're aware of it or not. Using `iter` simply gives you access to one at the code level. Anyway, it seems like your question is: given an iterator object, how can we call `next` on it a specified number of times? Well - how do you *normally* do *anything* a specified number of times in Python? With... a `for` loop, right? So....

Comment: "If I have to use an iterator object, then is it possible to do it a fixed amount of time?" - with an arbitrary iterator, no. Iterators are sequential, not random-access. For example, an iterator over a linked list cannot be advanced without following links one by one, and a generator doesn't even have well-defined elements until you run it and make it yield elements one by one.

Comment: If you're just iterating over a list, then you can skip in constant time easily enough, but not with a standard list iterator. You would have to write your own handling.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to have a C style `for` loop that has more complete update logic:

```
def cfor(i, test_i, update_i):
    while test_i(i):
        yield i
        i=update_i(i)

song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

skip=3

for i in cfor(0, 
              lambda i: i<len(song), 
              lambda i: i+skip+1 if song[i]=='look' else i+1):
    print(song[i], end=' ')
```

Or, that can just be a `while` loop:

```
idx=0
while(idx<len(song)):
    print(song[idx], end=' ')
    idx+=skip+1 if song[idx]=='look' else 1
```

If your `skip` is large, either of these would be faster.

---

You can also use `enumerate` with a comprehension:

```
l=song.index('look')
' '.join([w for i,w in enumerate(song) if i<=l or i>(l+skip)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1 There are many ways to do the problem one of the easiest one would be by checking the index like

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
skip_iterations=3
for i,sing in enumerate(song):
    if not song.index('look') < i < song.index('look')+skip_iterations+1:
    print(sing, end=" ")
```

'enumerate' returns (index, element)
Ans 2 Your method is just fine you may prefer a for loop instead of while loop but thats just a personal suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

You could employ the use of an iteration bound to keep track of when you can resume evaluation in the loop

```py
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

iter_bound = -1
for i, sing in enumerate(song):
    if i <= iter_bound:
        continue
    if sing == 'look':
        iter_bound = i + 3
    print(sing, end=" ")
```

If you use this very often in your code, you may want to code a function around it:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Callable

def skip_n_on_condition(iterator: Iterable, condition: Callable, n_skips: int):
    """Loop over iterable and perform n_skips whenever the condition on the element is met"""
    iter_bound = -1
    for i, element in enumerate(iterator):
        if i <= iter_bound:
            continue
        if condition(element):
            iter_bound = i + 3
        yield element
    
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

print(*skip_n_on_condition(song, lambda x: x == 'look', 3), end=" ")
```

**Question 2**

Since you know the number of times you will be looping, it may be better to use a **for** loop. It will also be an implementation that **does not change the value of skip_iterations** which you may not have expected.

```py
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)

skip_iterations = 3

for sing in song_iter:
    print(sing)
    if sing == "look":
        for _ in range(skip_iterations):
            next(song_iter, "")
```

You could make the loop a one liner using a list comprehension.

```py
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']
song_iter = iter(song)

skip_iterations = 3

for sing in song_iter:
    print(sing)
    if sing == "look":
        [next(song_iter, "") for _ in range(skip_iterations)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a skip counter:

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

skip = 0
for sing in song:
    if skip:
        skip -= 1
        continue
    print(sing, end=" ")
    if sing == 'look':
        skip = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the "historic" way of iterating.

```
song = ['always', 'look', 'on', 'the', 'bright', 'side', 'of', 'life']

i = 0
while i < len(song):
    sing = song[i]
    i += 1

    print(sing, end=" ")
    if sing == 'look':
        i += 3
        continue

    # ... other code ...
```